# What does this custom piece of frame manipulation code from a router binary do?

Tags: ida, elf, hexrays, pointer

I've decompiled a custom router ELF binary using Hex-Rays and have recently come across the following function in the binary:

```
pkt_hdr_t *__cdecl pkt_hdr_from_frame(frame_t *frame, uint16_t *remaining)
{
  uint16_t *remaininga; // [xsp+10h] [xbp+10h]
  frame_t *framea; // [xsp+18h] [xbp+18h]
  uint16_t frame_sz; // [xsp+26h] [xbp+26h]

  framea = frame;
  remaininga = remaining;
  if ( !frame || !remaining )
    return 0LL;
  frame_sz = ntohs(frame->sz.inner);
  if ( frame_sz <= 1u )
    return 0LL;
  *remaininga = frame_sz - 2;
  return (pkt_hdr_t *)&framea[1];
}
```

While it's a pretty short piece of code, I'll appreciate it if the role of `remaining` and the `return` line can be figured out. I know that a frame is created from a packet by appending the length of a packet to the beginning of it and the length field is 2 bytes long itself. This seems related to `remaining` which is a pointer to a 16 bit (2 byte) unsigned integer. According to the line before `return` it seems to me that initially the value pointed to by `remaining` is the length of the frame, i.e., length of packet + 2 bytes of length field but the function `pkt_hdr_from_frame` removes those 2 bytes and returns a pointer to the field in the frame located after the packet-length field (which is the beginning of the packet itself). Nevertheless, I'm confused with `framea[1]` as I don't understand the indexing here, especially considering the fact that the `frame_t` type is unknown to me. Thank you for your help!

**EDIT 1:** IDA Pro Local Types tab gives (Ordinal, Name, Size, Sync, Description) as

```
31  frame_t 00000002        struct {uint16_n sz;uint8_t data[];}
63  _pkt_hdr_t  00000002        struct {pkt_flags_t flags;msg_type_t msgtype;}
64  pkt_hdr_t   00000002        typedef _pkt_hdr_t
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ntohs basically converts a netshort to hostshort

```
>>> import socket
>>> print (hex(socket.ntohs(0x1337)))
0x3713
>>> print (hex(socket.ntohs(0x3713)))
0x1337
>>>
```

it will write back
0x3713-0x2 = 0x3711  or  0x1337 - 0x2 = 0x1335
in the address pointed by remaining if it is > 1u

and return back an address a pointer to pkt_hdr_t

comment edit

no remaining is an incoming pointer
it is a writable address
this function writes back whatever is remaining from the result of ntohs() call - 2 to this pointer
it is like *blah = foo where foo is an unsigned short and blah is a pointer to unsigned short

so it may be called like unsigned short * xyz = 0;
pkt_whatever(abc,xyz) {
xyz = some unsigned short whose value is 123xxyy
}

so on incoming xyz will be holding 0 when it goes out of the function xyz will be holding  123xxyy

Comment: So essentially my interpretation may be right, correct? In particular if the value pointed to by remaining is larger than 1, it will subtract 2 from it and write it to the same location. Also, can you comment on the indexing in `framea[1]`? Thanks for the brief illustration of `ntohs()` as well!

Comment: no you have a misunderstanding it is an incoming pointer it can be holding garbage or any value it was initialised with and most of the time it would be initialised with 0 and when the function returns it will hold whatever is the result of ntohs()-2 i also edited the answer

Comment: I'm so sorry, what I said made absolutely no sense. I actually meant what you just mentioned. No matter what the value pointed to by `remaining` is it will get updated to the value `ntohs()-2` if in fact the return value of `ntohs()` is larger than 1.